# Explicit scheme for the transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We consider the Transport equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)=0,\quad\quad (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^*_+$$
We approximate this equation by the following scheme

$$\frac{v_j^{n+1}-v_j^{n}}{\Delta t}+\frac{4}{3}\frac{v_{j+1}^{n}-v_{j-1}^{n}}{2\Delta x}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{v_{j+2}^{n}-v_{j-2}^{n}}{4\Delta x}=0$$

where $v_j^n\simeq u(x_j,t^n)$ with $x_j=j\Delta x$ and $t^n=n\Delta t$. We suppose that $\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$ is equal to a constant.

Could you please help me to write the scheme in the following form

$v_j^{n+1}=H(v_{j-1}^n,v_{j}^n,v_{j+1}^n)$.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here we would rather write
$$
v_j^{n+1} = H(v_{j-2}^n\dots v_{j+2}^n) 
$$
as the scheme has a five-point stencil. Hope you can take it from here